# Crystal Reports month to month comparison chart over two years

Tags: charts, crystal-reports

We are using Crystal Reports 2011 to generate a report with a number of charts. One chart in particular needs to display consumption (MBTU) for each month for over a two year span. We want to have similar months side by side so that it is easy to see the differences between the months. Here is a mockup showing what we want our chart to look like. The only difference is we want to show a full twelve months; Oct thru Sept.

[image: Month to Month Consumption Comparison]

Our data source is structured like so:

```
entity      'the entity we are summarizing
consumption 'raw consumption in MBTU
date        'this is a date field that includes month and year
```

However, we are unable to get our chart to display in this fashion. What we have accomplished is shown below.

[image]

We do not have data for beyond Sept 2012 which is why Oct,Nov,Dec 2012 is blank. However we do have data for Jan, Feb, Mar of 2011 but it is not displaying for some reason. Additionally, we want to the chart to start at Oct and run through Sep.

Our parameters in the chart expert are set to:

On Change of: @MonthName and @Year (in that order)
Show Values: consumption

Any thoughts as to how to acheive the effect we want within Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 0):

1. `we do have data for Jan, Feb, Mar of 2011 but it is not displaying for some reason`
   First, you should investigate that. Your dataset may not be what you think it is.
2. You can add a SQL Layer between your data source and the graph. You can do this in Crystal itself, at the data source, etc. It depends on your entire setup.   In this SQL Layer, you can do alot of custom coding, even crosstab your data by month to display months with no data at all.  However, a Where clause should suffice, i.e. something like `Where date>='20111001' and date <'20121001'`